# How to send SSID and password to a Raspberry Pi IoT device

Tags: configuration, raspberry-pi, wifi, iot, alexa-skills-kit

I've built an IoT device using a Raspberry Pi, let's say a kind of embedded device or an all-in-one device, anyway something closed with a Raspberry Pi doing all the operations. Imagine I want to sell this device to several clients. An end client should be able to do a first configuration by which he/she says "hey this is my device" and should send to the device (i.e. the raspberry) the SSID and the password of the network it should connect to. How can this configurations be done? What drives me mad is how to let the raspberry know the client's wifi credentials. For example, the echo dot during the first configuration it automatically gets the client's wifi credentials. How do they do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could configure the Raspberry Pi to offer its own wifi SSID, say `SpikeyIOT`, and instruct your end client to temporarily connect their smartphone/tablet/PC to that network.

On connection, they get transported/redirected to a [captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) that lets them put in their regular network SSID and password which you save (encrypted) on your Raspberry Pi's SD card and possibly disable the temporary network for subsequent reboots. Maybe provide a *"hard reset"* button that re-enables this temporary network to change the settings again later.